# Facing issue while installing rasa-x on windows using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, chatbot, rasa, rasa-x

error i'm getting--

ERROR: pip's legacy dependency resolver does not consider dependency conflicts when selecting packages. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.6.3 requires six~=1.15.0, but you'll have six 1.16.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.6.3 requires typing-extensions<3.11,>=3.7, but you'll have typing-extensions 4.0.1 which is incompatible.
rasa-sdk 2.8.4 requires typing-extensions<4.0.0,>=3.7.4, but you'll have typing-extensions 4.0.1 which is incompatible.
sanic-jwt 1.6.0 requires pyjwt==2.0.0, but you'll have pyjwt 2.3.0 which is incompatible.
rasa 2.8.23 requires aiohttp!=3.7.4.post0,<3.8,>=3.6, but you'll have aiohttp 3.8.1 which is incompatible.
rasa 2.8.23 requires apscheduler<3.8,>=3.6, but you'll have apscheduler 3.8.1 which is incompatible.
rasa 2.8.23 requires prompt-toolkit<3.0,>=2.0, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 3.0.27 which is incompatible.
rasa 2.8.23 requires sentry-sdk<1.3.0,>=0.17.0, but you'll have sentry-sdk 1.3.1 which is incompatible.

please look at image for more clarity of the error-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdxo0.png

Version using for Installation--

conda create -n rasavirtualenv python=3.7.6

pip install --upgrade pip==21.3

pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --use deprecated=legacy-resolver

Comment: What does the error recommend? Why don't you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is caused because of pip's version. You should downgrade the pip version and see if that works. So make sure the virtual environment with rasa is active and:

`pip install --upgrade pip==20.2`, then run `pip -V` to make sure the right version is installed, lastly run `pip install -U rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple` to install Rasa-x.